# Process list of files to format filenames for web (easy)

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, scripting

I realize this is dead simple but I don't write many scripts so risking stupid pride I'm hoping to learn a thing or two by asking such a basic question.

Given UNIX (Mac) how might you approach turning list (.txt) of filenames:

```
P4243419.JPG
P4243420.JPG
P4243423.JPG
...continues...
```

into .html something like:

```
<img src="http://imgs.domain.com/event/P4243419.JPG" title="Image File P4243419.JPG" />
<img src="http://imgs.domain.com/event/P4243420.JPG" title="Image File P4243420.JPG" />
<img src="http://imgs.domain.com/event/P4243423.JPG" title="Image File P4243423.JPG" />
...continues...
```

I know Ruby...but I would value additional language examples for such a simple task. What I'm not sure of is how to parameterize each line of the txt file (or filename in a directory) into the input for processing. The output is simple enough.

Comment: I don't understand - do you want a bash script, Ruby script, or a different language?

Comment: this is a completely independent script so open to any approach...curious to see how languages I may not be familiar with approach the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puts Dir['*.JPG'].map{ |f| "<img src='#{f}' title='Image File #{f}' />" }
```

**Edit**: Sorry, I misread. So you have a file with a bunch of filenames in it?

```
IO.read('myfile.txt').scan(/\S+/).map{ |f| "...#{f}..." }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lnwe 'print "<img src=\"http://host/$_\">"' filelist.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

Using a directory list:

```
for a in `ls *.JPG`; do echo "<img src=\"http://imgs.domain.com/event/$a\" title=\"Image File $a\" />"; done
```

From a file (file called *list*):

```
cat list | while read a;  do echo "<img src=\"http://imgs.domain.com/event/$a\" title=\"Image File $a\" />"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be not the most effective solution, but easy to understand:
Make a file img2link.sh

```
for file
do
    cat "$file" | grep -i jpg | while read image
    do
        echo "<img src=\"http://imgs.domain.com/event/$image\" title=\"Image File $image\" />"
    done
done
```

you can use your new command:

```
sh img2link.sh filename_with_images.txt another_filename_with_images.txt
```

The grep ensure than you will not process empty lines in the given files.

Answer (score 1):

for bash scripting, I see a couple of answers with `cat` -- not needed

```
format_string="<img src='http://imgs.domain.com/event/%s' title='Image File %s' />\n"
while read f; do
    printf "$format_string" "$f" "$f"
done < filename.txt
```